# Checking if a nominal variable is important in a GLM model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

Is it possible to put a nominal explanatory variable as a continuous variable in a GLM in R (instead of telling R that its a factor with different levels) to see if this variable (treatment) is a significant driver of the response variable that we are interested in before looking at the levels?

Thanks!

Comment: @why would you want to do that? You mean to code a nominal with arbitrary numbers (e.g. "blue" =2)?? Very bad idea.

Comment: What is a "significant driver"?

Comment: @ ttnphns (significant driver, I suppose a better word would be "determiner")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treating a nominal variable as continuous is never a good idea because a simple relabeling of the numerical value of the levels can lead to different estimates and different hypothesis test decisions, which is a very undesirable property.

It sounds like you want to know how to test the significance of a nominal variable without examining the difference between levels of the nominal variable - since this is a GLM (fit by maximum likelihood) you can do this with the likelihood ratio test. Suppose you have a number of 'other' covariates $X_{1}, ..., X_{p}$ and an $m$-level categorical variable with dummy variables $B_{1}, ..., B_{m-1}$ indicating which level (excluding the reference level) of the nominal variable you are in (in R, these variables are generated automatically and incorporated in the fit if the predictor is a factor). So, then you fit two models

$$ Y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \sum_{j=1}^{p} X_{ij} \beta_{j} + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} B_{k} \alpha_{k} + \varepsilon_{i} $$

and

$$ Y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \sum_{j=1}^{p} X_{ij} \beta_{j} + \varepsilon_{i} $$

where the second model reflects the belief that the nominal predictor has no effect (irrespective of the effect of particular levels). Extract the maximized log-likelihoods from the first and second model $L_{1}, L_{0}$, respectively, (using, for example the logLik() function in R) and calculate

$$ 2 \Big( L_{1} - L_{0} \Big) $$

which has an approximate $\chi^{2}_{m-1}$ distribution, which you can use for significance testing.

Comment: When you say "use for significance testing" do you mean as a p-value?

Comment: and thanks for the very informative and excellent answer. I appreciate the time put into the answer, thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. When I say significance testing I mean that the $p$-value will be calculated by using areas under the $\chi^{2}_{m-1}$ distribution (and not, for example, the normal).

Comment: okay, so my model with the nominal variable of interest with all the levels gives a maximized log-likelihood value of (-16.8898) after using the MASS logLik() function as you mentioned. The null model gives -15.87208. This gives -0.66802 I believe using your above formula. "using areas under the χ2m−1 distribution" how do I do this? Excuse my inept understanding....

Comment: Well, that is fishy, because your null model gives a larger log-likelihood than the larger model (which is impossible). Do you have those mixed up? I also need to know how many levels your categorical variable has. It should also be noted that when I said "approximate" I meant that the test is valid for large samples. Your small log-likelihood values make me think you might be working with small samples.

Comment: If there are any missing values in the categorical predictor then R will eliminate them automatically from the model and they will be treated as though they don't exist - this may be a reason why the null model has a larger log-likelihood (since the likelihood scales with the sample size, and the sample size is smaller). If this is the case, the log-likelihoods are not comparable and you'd have to remove the missing cases before doing the test to make them comparable.

Comment: My nullmodel with missing cases removed gives
-15.04497 (df=12). Model1 which has the nominal variable removed gives a baffling -15.12846 (df=11). I am working with a small sample size yes.

Comment: You seem to have to role of the null and alternative model confused - the one with more parameters (df=12) is not the null model. In this case, your likelihood ratio test is incredibly small, indicating little is gained from adding the predictor. Also, the difference in degrees of freedom indicates that your categorical predictor has only two levels. If this isn't the case, you may have made a mistake. Make sure you declare the variable as a factor before fitting the model