# GLM model validation

Tags: r, model-selection, generalized-linear-model, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

When performing model validation and we are dropping the least significant explanatory variables until we find the optimum model where all remaining variables are significant, how does one go about dropping a particular "unimportant level" within a nominal variable? In my output below I have run a Neg. bin. GLM inorder to test abundance against the various explanatory variables listed. (as.factor(JJ)2) is the most obviously insignificant variable that I would like to drop but because it is a factor with three levels I don't know how to do this. (Of course I will have to rejig the data to unmask baseline values that are within the intercept also) Thanks!

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     3.351414   0.945861   3.543 0.000395 ***
DD              0.039417   0.011373   3.466 0.000528 ***
EE             -0.001497   0.001015  -1.475 0.140093    
PP             -0.138303   0.094287  -1.467 0.142423    
as.factor(BB)2 -0.901877   0.365796  -2.466 0.013682 *  
as.factor(JJ)1  0.495985   0.198394   2.500 0.012420 *  
as.factor(JJ)2 -0.276830   0.374576  -0.739 0.459878   
as.factor(VV)2 -0.499569   0.174710  -2.859 0.004244 ** 
as.factor(VV)3 -0.166065   0.175430  -0.947 0.343834    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(4.8369) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 97.392  on 46  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 47.883  on 38  degrees of freedom
AIC: 401.37
```

Comment: What's your model?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik What do you mean?

Comment: What formula did you use for constructing this model?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik I carried out the analysis via an interface through R but it is something like: glm.nb<-Abundance ~ DD + EE + PP + as.factor(BB) + as.factor(JJ) + as.factor(VV)

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Rather model<-glm.nb(Abundance~DD+EE+PP+as.factor(BB) + as.factor(JJ) + as.factor(VV))

Comment: @Platypezid As you seem to have been performed stepwise regression, please update your question with the precise R commands you used and the structure of your data (I can see three numerical variables and three categorical variables with 2 or 3 levels).

Comment: @Platypzeid - stepwise regression is almost always a bad idea, even when you do it by hand.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe Hey fello UCC corkonian :-) Why is stepwise regression bad? Can you not make inferences about the most important explanatory variables based on a reduced model?

Comment: Stepwise regression destroys all aspects of statistical inference (bias, type I error, false standard errors, inflated regression coefficients, inflated $R^2$, false confidence interval coverage).  Breaking apart components of categorical variables is even worse.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for that Frank. I have seen quite a few people making inferences based on a reduced model and it is upsetting because in essence, nothing in the natural world is always and solely reliant on the workings of specific environmental or otherwise conditions without hinging on one or many others....its just pseudo statistics

Comment: Yes, this relates to LJ Savage's antiparsimony principle.  The world, outside of very controlled physical experiments, is too complex to expect simpler models to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the significance of a nominal variable without inspecting individual level effects by using the likelihood ratio test, comparing the model with and without the variable. I've answered this exact question in [Checking if a nominal variable is important in a GLM model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14269/checking-if-a-nominal-variable-is-important-in-a-glm-model/14298#14298)

Comment: I understand the loglik() approach, however, what I really want to know is whether you can keep one level of a nominal variable in a model to help better explain the data. i.e. If significantly more birds were found in relation to a particular level of say a tree canopy with three levels (e.g. low in comparison to medium and high) then isn't this important in the optimum model?

Comment: Checking individual levels is, in some sense, a "post-hoc" test that is usually done after determining (via some omnibus test) that the variable as a whole is significant. So, I would advise testing the variable and, if significant, consider pairing down to sub-levels (although that may cause interpretability problems). It might be best to go "all or nothing" when doing model selection.

Comment: Well put, @Macro

Comment: @Macro Yes, thanks very much. This is a valid take on the problem and explained with a deep understanding, thanks a million, I see the issues now.

Comment: @Platypezid - Glad I could help. Also, just in general, if you have found an answer helpful and definitive, please consider accepting the answer - I noticed you've yet to accept an answer on the several questions you've asked.

Comment: @Macro - Ah, sorry about that! Im relatively new to the site so I'll do that thanks Macro :-)

Answer (score 5):

In general, I am wary of step-wise variable elimination and model selection.  I would suggest using the lasso, elastic net, or ridge regression for variable penalization and selection. Check out the R packages [lars](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lars/index.html), [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html), and [lm.ridge](http://www.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/R/html/MASS/html/lm.ridge.html) in [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html).